# Как исправить код в следующем примере?

Tags: python

Нужно сделать равнобедренный треугольник из `#` используя `input`.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    print(' ' * (n - i) + '#' * (i + 1) + "#" * (i))
```

Вот код, но он не подходит для больших чисел. Если ввести больше 20, то треугольник становится прямоугольным.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Код без изменений, треугольник - равнобедренный
[пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a60CE.png)

Comment: Не может быть, что при больше 20 выводится другой результат. В коде число 20 никак не учитывается, поэтому результат одинаков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
        print(' ' * (n - (i+1)) + '#' * (i + 1) + "#" * (i))
```

**(n - (i+1))**